# PDO Search Script Not Showing Results With Template System

Tags: php, mysql, templates, pdo, view

I'm a bit new to PHP so this has got me a bit confused. I assume it's not an error within the code but rather the code logic.

There are two template files at use here:

Search - Which displays the search page.
search_item - Which is formatting for the returned results of the search.

I have dumped the execution of the query and it is returning true so this leads me to believe the query is successful and has received data from the form.

Below is the function for the Search.php page. (Displayed in the url as index.php?action=search from the controller)

```
public function handleAction() {

    global $user, $config;

    $database = Database::getDatabase();
    $driver = $database->getDriver();
    $search = $_POST['keywords'];
    $stmt = $driver->prepare('SELECT * FROM clansoc_clans WHERE clan_name LIKE :keywords');
    $stmt->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $search . '%');
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = array();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $results[] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'clan_name' => htmlspecialchars($row['clan_name'], ENT_QUOTES),
            'short_desc' => htmlspecialchars($row['clan_short_desc'], ENT_QUOTES),
            'clan_avatar' => $row['clan_avatar']
        );

    }

    $results_list_registry = new ViewRegistry();
    $results_list = new View('Results List', $results_list_registry, false);
    $results_list_contents = "";
    //$i = $offset;

    foreach($results as $result) {

        $results_list_result_registry = new ViewRegistry();
        $this->view->getViewRegistry()->setVariable('id', $result['id']);
        $this->view->getViewRegistry()->setVariable('name', $result['clan_name']);
        $this->view->getViewRegistry()->setVariable('desc', $result['short_desc']);
        $this->view->getViewRegistry()->setVariable('avatar', $result['clan_avatar']);
        $results_list_result = new View('Results List Result', $results_list_result_registry);
        $results_list_result->setView('search_item');
        $results_list_contents .= $results_list_result->export(false);
    }

    $results_list->setView($results_list_contents);
    $this->view->getViewRegistry()->setVariable('results', $results_list);

}
```

My question in simpler terms:

Why is the script not displaying the results of the query?

Comment: you don't need both loops and dump $row to see if you really have data

Comment: Returning true does not mean its returned results, why dont you run the SQL directly on the Database first or simply print_r($results); die(); after the while loop to make sure it isnt empty. Basically are you 100% certain the sql retursn results, have you checked what $_POST['keywords'] is etc...

Comment: @NaN The query is running successfully and does return data.

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 12 [clan_name] => ClanSoC - Official Clan [short_desc] => This is the official clan of the ClanSoC community! [clan_avatar] => assets/uploads/1425523363-default_avatar.jpg ) ) `

EDIT: It is also returning that same line of data even when the search variable is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately then I would say its impossible to solve the problem by viewing this script alone as it could be anything in any one of the Classes/Methods it  uses (ViewRegistry(), View())